# Streaming audio from Twilio media stream to a browser

Tags: twilio, streaming, html5-audio

I'm trying to stream audio from a Twilio call to a browser.

I want to use Twilio Media Streams which send base64 encoded data in 8000 sample rate, audio/x-mulaw (according to this: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream)

I tried playing back the audio in a browser using `audioContext.decodeAudioData` but I am getting an exception:

`DOMException: The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type.`

I think I need to resample the data and add a header or something of that sort but I'm unable to figure it out.

Any help would be much appreacited

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I have not tried this myself, so I can only give some pointers. You are right that the audio from Twilio is coming as `audio/x-mulaw` and that browsers do not support this format.

There is a good set of documentation on MDN about [web audio codecs and containers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Audio_codecs). CanIUse has data on browser support for common formats (e.g. [mp3](https://caniuse.com/?search=mp3)).

So you will need to resample the audio into a supported format before you send it to the browser. I don't have any suggestions for tools for that, particularly as I don't know what you are building your server in.

Alternatively, if you need the audio from a call in a browser, have you considered using [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) to dial into the call?

Comment: Thank you @philnash I did consider that and in fact, we are using it in another use case. The question how can I dial into an ongoing call (and later hangup w/o interrupting the call)?

Comment: You would want the call to be a conference. Are you looking for features like coaching or taking over calls? Take a look at the [Agent conference features](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/agent-conference-generally-available.html).